# vaadin 7 missing web.xml file change default page

Tags: vaadin, web.xml

im new to vaadin but noticed that you can in vaadin 6 set the default page in the web.xml file but in vaadin 7 this has been done away with. 
how do i change the default page ?

Thanks

Comment: you can still configure the default page in web.xml. Make sure that you have configured the right settings like servlet url mapping, /VAADIN/ etc

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean by "default page", so I have to make some guesses.

As you say that you are missing the web.xml, you probably mean a project created by Vaadin Plugin for Eclipse or the Maven archetype. By default, the wizard (or Maven archetype) creates a project stub that uses Servlet API 3.0 deployment with @WebServlet annotation for the servlet class, which is a static class nested in the UI class. It can also be a regular (non-nested and non-static) class, but that's how it is in the application stub.

If you choose Servlet API 2.4 for the new Vaadin 7 Eclipse project, it will use web.xml to define the servlet and UI class, as well as their parameters.

You can mix @WebServlet and web.xml deployment, in which case settings done in web.xml override the ones given with @WebServlet annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Default page to serve is not actually a need to be defined since the framwork handles everything, especially with 3.0 servlet implementation.
But sometimes one may need such file (like, for example, to add context listeners for Spring).
So you can either select the option to generate it during project creation or just make a blank web.xml file in WebContent/WEB-INF.

The autogenerated plugin file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>YOUR_APP_NAME</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```